# exec without opening cmd

Tags: windows, go

On windows, how I can execute a command from Go's `exec` without opening a terminal window?

eg:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("ping", "www.google.com")
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
  return err
}
```

This opens a cmd window when running the command.

I compile it with `go build -ldflags="-H windowsgui"`, the app then doesn't open a cmd window, but when it gets to `cmd.Run()` it opens one.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that. Yes it is on windows.

Comment: @icza, this is not the correct duplicate. The question you found is about making the Go program itself not open a terminal, not a program that is executed with exec.Command.

Comment: @Peter Yes, realized after I marked it.

Comment: `cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}` worked for me.